# getting 404 error while calling a jsp page using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
<script>
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
    alert('jquery call');
    window.open('referCandidate.jsp','_blank');
 });
</script>
```

getting error as requested resource not available.

Comment: Where is your referCandidate.jsp file ?

Comment: under WEB-INF/views/..in the same location both jsp pages are located

Comment: window.open(/views/referCandidate.jsp,'_blank'); - try with this ?

Comment: I guess There is some mismatch on your path . Try '../referCandidate.jsp' or  '../views/referCandidate.jsp' or @javaguy  suggestion.

Comment: getting error as - This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8090/views/referCandidate.jsp

Comment: What is the URL of the page calling the request?

Comment: A simple explanation is that you can't access file in `WEB-INF` directly. So if you have anyy sort of redirection, could you share it please.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spring project . if so then add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

to the config file. This will resolve the view to /WEB-INF/view/referCandidate.jsp.

Ref: [Setting the default jsp view with spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511301/setting-the-default-jsp-view-with-spring-mvc)

You can invoke like localhost:8090/referCandidate.jsp

Comment: You are taking a big bet here, is it a sping project or not ? You don't have anything tell you that for now.